# Vue CLI build - develop locally with "/" as root but deploy to "/subfolder/" as root?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I have a Vue locally, the main `/index.html` is the webroot but when I deploy, I want the subfolder `/stats` to be the root (and all my routes to still work).

Can I do this without manually changing my router/index.js?

**vue.config.js**

```
// this doesn't seem to work
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/stats/" : "/",
};
```

**router.js**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "HomeView",
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: "/grid",
    name: "GridView",
    component: GridView,
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only recommendation I'd make sure you set router `base` property to match your `publicPath`

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL, //  set the "base" property here
  routes
})
```